# FETCH toma datos viejos de un archivo

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

Tengo un archivo llamado **'information.json'** en el que almaceno usuarios y contraseñas. En un momento cambié algunos datos de dicho archivo y al utilizar *FETCH* para obtener la información, me devuelve los datos viejos, no los nuevos. Probé de borrar el archivo y aun así sin el archivo en la carpeta me devuelve los datos. Supongo que se debe al caché, pero desconozco la solución para esto.

Un dato extra: utilizo XAMPP como servidor.

Comment: Si ese archivo va a sufrir cambios durante la vida del software, lo mejor es que lo sirvas con un header no-cache, si no vas a verte en este mismo problema, pero en producción y no debieras ir pidiendo a los clientes que limpien el navegador del browser cada vez que cambia el archivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de evitar borrar el cache es utilizar dev tools para evitar que cargue el caché, seleccionando la pestaña red.

[image: Seleccionando devtools]

Una segunda opción es dar click derecho en la llamada que estás haciendo, debería aparecer en el listado de la pestaña red, aparecerá el menú contextual y debes seleccionar borrar caché.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]